# Changing a table border of html using javascript switch?

Tags: javascript

This is the code I have so far.No idea what syntax to use to get the border to change in that small table. I know my code doesn't work. I just need some help on getting the bordernumber variable to change the border of the table.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
var choice;
var validInput=true;
var bordernumber;

choice=window.prompt( "Please select a size for table border:\n" + "3(3 Pixel
   Border)\n 5(5 Pixel Border)\n 7 (7 Pixel Border)\n 9 (9 Pixel Border)\n");

switch(choice){
case "3":
bordernumber= "3";
break;
case "5":
bordernumber="5";
break;
case "7":
bordernumber="7";
break;
case "9":
bordernumber="9";
break;
default:
validInput=false;
break;
}
if (validInput===true){
document.getElementsById.border='bordernumber';
}
else
document.write("error");

</script>
<table border="7">
<tr>
<td>100</td>
<td>200</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>300</td>
<td>400</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>`
```

Comment: does `document.getElementsById.border=bordernumber` without the quotes work?

Answer (score 0):

To call `getElementById()` (it's singular), you need an `id` on the `table`. Then use the *value* of `bordernumber`, not the *string* `"bordernumber"`:

```js
var choice;
var validInput=true;
var bordernumber;

choice=window.prompt( "Please select a size for table border:\n" + 
  "3(3 Pixel Border)\n 5(5 Pixel Border)\n 7 (7 Pixel Border)\n 9 (9 Pixel Border)\n");

switch(choice){
  case "3":
  case "5":
  case "7":
  case "9":
    bordernumber = choice;
    break;
    
  default:
    validInput=false;
    break;
}

if (validInput===true){
  document.getElementById('mytable').border=bordernumber;
}
else
  document.write("error");
```

```html
<table border="7" id="mytable">
<tr>
<td>100</td>
<td>200</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>300</td>
<td>400</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.  You will need to add an id to your table for this:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
var choice;
var validInput=true;
var bordernumber;

choice=window.prompt( "Please select a size for table border:\n" + "3(3 Pixel
   Border)\n 5(5 Pixel Border)\n 7 (7 Pixel Border)\n 9 (9 Pixel Border)\n");

switch(choice){
case "3":
bordernumber= "3";
break;
case "5":
bordernumber="5";
break;
case "7":
bordernumber="7";
break;
case "9":
bordernumber="9";
break;
default:
validInput=false;
break;
}
if (validInput===true){
document.getElementById("myTable").style.border = bordernumber;
}
else
document.write("error");

</script>
<table id="myTable" border="7">
<tr>
<td>100</td>
<td>200</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>300</td>
<td>400</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is a complete newbie mess. This is the best I can do for you:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<body>

    <table id="myTable" border="7">
        <tr>
            <td>100</td>
            <td>200</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>300</td>
            <td>400</td>
        </tr>
    </table>

<script type="text/javascript">

var choice=window.prompt( "Please select a size for table border:\n" + "3(3 Pixel Border)\n 5(5           Pixel Border)\n 7 (7 Pixel Border)\n 9 (9 Pixel Border)\n");

if(isNaN(choice) || choice % 2 == 0 || choice < 3 || choice > 9){
    document.write("error");
}
else{
    document.getElementById("myTable").style.borderWidth = choice + "px";
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/4nsyu63w/

Answer (score 0):

You have two ways of doing this. One method is to add an id to the table and use `document.getElementById(id).style.property=new style`

The other method is to use `document.getElementsByTagName(tagName).style.property=new style`

**method one**

```
document.getElementById("tableId").style.borderWidth = choice
```

**method two**

```
document.getElementsByTagName("table").style.borderWidth = choice
```